# Java 8 localdatetime vs Date

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I have a string `2017-07-31T01:01:00-07:00` and I am trying to parse it to date and in CST Timezone. I am getting different results when i parse this string using Date and Java 8 ZonedDateTime. I am not getting why this is happening and what I am doing wrong.

```
    String dateStr = "2017-07-31T01:01:00-07:00";
    LocalDateTime time = null;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-hh");

    String[] dateArray = dateStr.split("-");
    String[] timeZones = TimeZone
            .getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-" + dateArray[dateArray.length - 1]).getRawOffset());
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZones[0]));
    Date dateObj = null;
    try {
        dateObj = format.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    time = dateObj.toInstant().atZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST").toZoneId()).toLocalDateTime();
    ZonedDateTime time2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr).toInstant().atZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST").toZoneId());
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(time2.toLocalDateTime());
```

Comment: Why do you manually extract the time zone - limited to 0..9. This will run into problems for a lot of location in the world.

Comment: *"I am getting different results"* Show us. Don't expect us to run your code to see it. Edit the question and show your results.

Comment: When you can use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API to which `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` belong, why do you want to worry about the outmoded classes like `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` at all? My recommendation would be to forget about them.

Comment: And by CST, do you mean China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time? Those three and four letter time zone abbreviations are so d*** ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

You should not parse the timezone offset yourself. Just use the `X` pattern:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
```

You should not use timezone `CST`, since that is ambiguous (Central Standard Time, China Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time). Use `America/Chicago` (I assume that's what you meant).

So, to parse the date string with old and new APIs:

```
String dateStr = "2017-07-31T01:01:00-07:00";

// Using Date
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date date = parseFormat.parse(dateStr);

SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
printFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(printFormat.format(date));

// Using ZonedDateTime
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr);
zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime());
```

*Output*

```
2017-07-31T03:01
2017-07-31T03:01
```

If you want to see the time zone, you can do this:

```
String dateStr = "2017-07-31T01:01:00-07:00";

// Using Date
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date date = parseFormat.parse(dateStr);

SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm XXX z");
printFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(printFormat.format(date));

// Using ZonedDateTime
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr);

DateTimeFormatter printFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm XXX z")
                                                    .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(printFormatter));
```

*Output*

```
2017-07-31T03:01 -05:00 CDT
2017-07-31T03:01 -05:00 CDT
```

Note how the first example changes the `ZonedDateTime` timezone, converts it to a `LocalDateTime`, then prints that without a formatter, while in the second example the `DateTimeFormatter` is setup to format the value in a specific timezone, similar to how the `SimpleDateFormat` is doing it. Just different ways of accomplishing the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the exact behaviour of `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs` (it’s not perfectly well documented). When I run your code on my Java 9.0.4, the first ID it returns is America/Boise. Boise, Idaho, USA, is on Mountain Standard Time in winter (UTC-07:00) and on Mountain Daylight Time now (UTC-06:00). You set your `format` to use this for parsing. Your format parses `01` as hour of day (uppercase `HH`, 00 through 23) *and* `07` as hour within AM or PM (lowercase `hh`, 01 through 12). So there’s a conflict here. Apparently the former wins, I don’t know why (don’t always insist on understanding `SimpleDateFormat`). Since July 31 is in the summer time (DST) time of year, you get a time of 01:01-06:00, equal to 02:01 North American Central Daylight Time (-05:00). Which is incorrect.

`ZonedDateTime.parse` parses your string correctly. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST").toZoneId()` interprets CST as America/Chicago (which strictly speaking is incorrect since Chicago uses CST only for the minor part of the year). So in `time2` you get `2017-07-31T03:01-05:00[America/Chicago]`, which is correct.

For what I think you were trying to obtain I recommend:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
    System.out.println(dateTime.toLocalDateTime());
```

Output is the same as your second output:

> 2017-07-31T03:01

If you find it more appropriate for your situation, instead of America/Chicago you may consider for example America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Indiana/Knox, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Matamoros, America/Menominee or America/Winnipeg. Don’t rely on a three or four letter time zone abbreviation. CST is not a true time zone since it is only used for some of the year, and it is ambiguous, it may refer to Australian Central Standard Time, North and Central American Central Standard Time, China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time. And there’s no guarantee which one Java gives you.